# How to blink the text on windows terminal using python

Tags: python, colorama

This is the code I wrote. But not able to achieve the desired result.

```
import colorama
colorama.init()

text=colored("HI THERE!", color="magenta", on_color="on_cyan", attrs=["blink"])
print(text)

# how to make text blink using colorama?
```

Comment: Blinking text isn't supported by the Windows command line. Maybe [Hyper](https://hyper.is) would be up your alley.

Comment: it is not working

Comment: it's printing this one [5m[45m[33mHI THERE![0m

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print something on the cmd you need to use a module as its not supported with pythons standard libaries.
take a look at this module: https://wiki.python.org/moin/CmdModule